# CSS Bottom Positioning

Tags: html, css

So, I have this:

```
.cmon
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("line2.png");
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

What it should do, is put the image (line in this case) on the bottom of the page, from what I understand, and repeat it. It does put it on the bottom, but doesn't repeat, anybody knows what's my problem?
This is how it looks like when the code is on:
http://goolag.pw/temptest.html
Also, in the menu (top right corner) the image doesn't even show up, nor does is it on the bottom.
I will be more than happy if anybody knows whats the problem.
(sorry if links are not allowed here, there are no commercials on the web, it's really just to show what's the problem)

Comment: Using `position:absolute`, any empty `<div>` has no `width` or `height`. You may need to set these. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm6nU/).

Comment: What @showdev said. You _must_ set the width and height of absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Thank you @AlexB., your example helped me, now it works. Thank you very much.
Please put it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position background images you should use the [`background-position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```css
.cmon {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("line2.png");
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

> The `background-position` CSS property sets the initial position, relative to the background position layer defined by `background-origin` for each defined background image.

You'll need to ensure your element has some `height` and `width`, however, as background images are not content and do not affect the size of the element.

Comment: Yes, about the last comment, I didn't F5 before writing it, so I only saw the first one. Gonna try it out.

Comment: `.cmon {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("line2.png");
    background-position: bottom;
 width:966px;
 height:4px;
}
<div class="cmon"></div>
`
Well, this is what I've done, just as you said, but for some reason it doesn't still repeat and/or it isn't on the bottom of the page.
It's basically on the top left corner of the page.

Comment: @TwiXSK You seem to have removed your absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

So first, your problem is not only about CSS but HTML too. You have to attach your attribute  `.cmon` on another tag like `<span>`, `<p>`or even `<div>`.

```
<div class="cmon"></div>
```

Then for your CSS :

```
.cmon {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("line2.png");
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    left: 0px; right: 0px; // For having a full width bar
    z-index: 999999; // Will be always visible, even when the menu is showed up
    height: 4px; // attribute the height of your image
}
```

Hope this help you.

Ps : Don't forget to use HTML5 !